# Map reduce to count the unique count

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want a map reduce function to draw the below output from the below input collection which satisfy the below condition.

Input collection:

```
[{

    a:1,
    b:'test',
    indices:[1,2,4,5]
}, {
    a:2,
    b:'test',
    indices:[2, 3, 5]
}, {
    a:2,
    b:'test',
    indices:[1, 2, 4]
}, {
    a:3,
    b:'apple',
    indices:[1, 2]
}, {
    a:4,
    b:'apple',
    indices:[1, 3, 5]
}, {
    a:5,
    b:'orange',
    indices:[232]
}, {
    a:5,
    b:'dummy',
    indices:[2]
}, {
    a:6,
    b:'dummy',
    indices:[11, 2, 4]
}, {
    a:6,
    b:'dummy',
    indices:[11, 3, 2]
}, {
    a:6,
    b:'dummy',
    indices:[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
}]
```

Conditions are:

1. select only which has indices array has `2`. This can be send as
   query. i.e, query:{indices:{$in:2}}
2. Group by `b`
3. If there are duplicates `a`, then it should be considered as `1` eg: Document having a=2 are present in two times satisfying the condition indices
   has 2.
4. My input collection always satisfies the condition of if a
   prsents in "test", it will not present in `dummy/apple/etc`. but a
   can be duplicate.

Here is what I tried:

```
db.x.mapReduce(function(){
        emit(this.b, 1);
    }, function(key, reducable){
        return Array.sum(reducable);
    }, {
    out: {inline: 1},
    query:{
        'indices':{$in:2}
    }
    });
```

Output:
    [

```
{
    "_id" : test",
    "value" : {
        "count" : 3 -> It should be 2
    }
},{
    "_id" : apple",
    "value" : {
        "count" : 2
    }
},{
    "_id" : dummy",
    "value" : {
        "count" : 4 -> It should be 2
    }
}]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
    "_id" : test",
    "value" : {
        "count" : 2
    }
},{
    "_id" : apple",
    "value" : {
        "count" : 2
    }
},{
    "_id" : dummy",
    "value" : {
        "count" : 2
    }
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for map/reduce. Use aggregation:

```
> db.crawler_status.aggregate([
    { "$match" : { "indices" : 2 } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : { "b" : "$b", "a" : "$a" } } },
    { "$group" : { "_id" : "$_id.b", "count" : { "$sum" : 1 } } }
])
{ "_id" : "test", "count" : 2 }
{ "_id" : "apple", "count" : 1 }    // your sample output was mistaken
{ "_id" : "dummy", "count" : 2 }
```